# SQL - How to use parent selected id in child select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make a query with a CASE statement that uses a second select, and in that second select, i need to use parent's selected id in a where clause.

It would look like something like this :

```
    SELECT "OFF_ID" AS "ID_P",
    CASE 
       WHEN 
         ( SELECT "OFF_NUMBER" FROM "OFFER_COPY" 
          WHERE "OFF_C_ID" = "ID_P" <-- I need to map to the parent ID
         ) > 0
       THEN 'JOHN'
       ELSE  'DOE'
        END AS "TEST",
    FROM "OFFER"
```

Comment: Qualify the columns! (I.e. `"table-name"."column-name"`.)

Comment: You should **really** avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run then they are worth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always qualify your column names, particularly in a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT o."OFF_ID" AS "ID_P",
       (CASE WHEN (SELECT oc."OFF_NUMBER"
                   FROM "OFFER_COPY" oc
                   WHERE oc."OFF_C_ID" = o."OFF_ID" 
                  ) > 0
             THEN 'JOHN' ELSE  'DOE'
        END) AS "TEST",
FROM "OFFER" o
```